# How to limit the number of Cloud Function triggers from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I created a function that is triggered when a new data created in Realtime Database. The problem is that the activity in the nodes could be very frequent, so the function could be called every second. Is there a way to limit the number of triggers in a period? For example, when 100 new data consecutively created in a minute, the function will be triggered only once and only by the last data created and other 99 will never be processed. I know there is a way to schedule the function to call in every minute instead of triggering it for new data in the db, but this is not efficient if some nodes have very rare activity while some have very frequent.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to implement what you're describing.  Cloud Functions will always trigger for every matching event from the source that it tracks.  There is no way to suspend or suppress events.  If this is going to be too frequent (by whatever measure you use for frequency), you will need to change the way you write the database, or some up with some other solution.